# kotlin top-level scopint issues

Tags: kotlin, scoping

With Kotlin scoping in the top-level (i.e. outside of the class) is public and static, right?
I have to files, where one has a data class and the other is trying to access it.

File1:

```
package com.test

data class Xyz (val s1:String, val s2:String)
```

File2:

```
package com.test

val myList : List<Xyz> = File1.theList
```

My error:

```
/home/sjs/Test/src/com/test/File2.kt
Error:(3, 26) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: File1
```

Files are in the same directory and have same package so I shouldn't have to import anything, right?  Also I've tried importing "import File1.*" and also "import com.test.File1.*" and nothing seem to work.

I've tried everything I can think of but the first file can't see the second.  I'm totally confused.

I'm using Intellij's IDE.
NOTE: Updated the code as suggested below and the compiler complained about needing a getter/setter which the code now has:

File1:

```
package com.test

data class Xyz (val s1:String, val s2:String)

val theList : List<Xyz>
    get() = buildList()

fun buildList() : List<Xyz> {
    var myList = mutableListOf<Xyz>()
    if (theList.size > 0) return theList;
    val l1 = arrayListOf<String>("1", "2", "3")
    val l2 = arrayListOf<String>("a", "b", "c")
    for (i in 0..l1.lastIndex)
        myList.add(Xyz(l1[i], l2[i]))
    return myList;
}
```

File2:

```
package com.test

val myList : List<Xyz> theList
```

The error:

```
/home/sjs/Test/src/com/test/File2.kt
Error:(3, 24) Kotlin: Property getter or setter expected
```

So -- now it's not seeing the getter()??

Answer (score 0):

These files are in the same package, so you don't need to import them. Also you don't need to specify the name of file:

```
val myList : List<Xyz> = theList
```

(If `theList` is a top-level property in File1)

In general, the name of .kt file is used to call something only when calling Kotlin top-level functions/properties from Java code.

Comment: I tried that at one point.  Doing that now it complains about no "property getter or setter expected so I added one (code above) and for some reason itt still complains.

Comment: It complains because in `buildLIst` you use `theList`, that uses `buildList` to compute itself. And if you write a getter like `get() = buildList()`, then `buildList()` will be called every time you try to access `theList`. If you want to initialize `theLIst` with the result of `buildList()` and save the result into property, just declare property like this: `val theList: List<Xyz> = buildList()` (You still need to remove accessing `theList` inside of `buildList` function).